# CFSocketSendData function problems with second argument

Tags: iphone, ios, sockets

I'm doing some tests with iPhone Sockets. This is the code (it works):

```
struct sockaddr_in destinationAddress;
socklen_t sockaddr_destaddr_len = sizeof(destinationAddress);
CFSocketError socket_error = 0;

CFSocketRef socket = CFSocketCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault,  
                                    AF_INET, 
                                    SOCK_STREAM,
                                    IPPROTO_TCP,
                                    kCFSocketNoCallBack,
                                    NULL,
                                    NULL);

if (!socket) {
    NSLog(@"CfSocketCreate Failed");
}

memset(&destinationAddress, 0, sockaddr_destaddr_len);
destinationAddress.sin_len = sockaddr_destaddr_len;
destinationAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
destinationAddress.sin_port = htons(23678);
destinationAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

NSData *destinationAddressData = [NSData dataWithBytes:&destinationAddress length:sizeof(destinationAddress)];

NSString *message = @"data to send, new line\n";
NSData *message_data = [message dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

CFSocketConnectToAddress(socket, (CFDataRef) destinationAddressData, 10);
socket_error = CFSocketSendData (socket, NULL, (CFDataRef) message_data, 10);

// show the status
if(socket_error < 0){
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Socket situation"
                                                    message:@"Socket error"
                                                   delegate:self 
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" 
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
```

So, first of all I open the connection to another socket (my log server). Second, I send data through the CFSockectSendData with 2nd NULL parameter in order to use the connection opened before. The problem is when I try to send the data directly by using the CFSocketSendData function, without using the CFSocket CFSocketConnectToAddress function before. The code become:

```
struct sockaddr_in destinationAddress;
socklen_t sockaddr_destaddr_len = sizeof(destinationAddress);
CFSocketError socket_error = 0;

CFSocketRef socket = CFSocketCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault,  
                                    AF_INET, 
                                    SOCK_STREAM,
                                    IPPROTO_TCP,
                                    kCFSocketNoCallBack,
                                    NULL,
                                    NULL);

if (!socket) {
    NSLog(@"CfSocketCreate Failed");
}

memset(&destinationAddress, 0, sockaddr_destaddr_len);
destinationAddress.sin_len = sockaddr_destaddr_len;
destinationAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
destinationAddress.sin_port = htons(23678);
destinationAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

NSData *destinationAddressData = [NSData dataWithBytes:&destinationAddress length:sizeof(destinationAddress)];

NSString *message = @"data to send, new line\n";
NSData *message_data = [message dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

socket_error = CFSocketSendData (socket, (CFDataRef) destinationAddressData, (CFDataRef) message_data, 10);

// show the status
if(socket_error < 0){
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Socket situation"
                                                    message:@"Socket error"
                                                   delegate:self 
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" 
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
```

In this case I collect an error with CFSocketSendData and an alert view will be showed. What is the error?
Simply I removed the CFSocketConnectToAddress function because the CFSocketSendData with second parameter not NULL should be able to connect to a specific address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. TCP is a connection-oriented protocol. You must establish a connection before you can send any data. It doesn't "connect to a specific address" for you because the point of being able to specify a destination address is to be able to reuse the same socket for multiple destinations. What would happen if you called CFSocketSendData() with a different address? Would the old connection close? If not, how would you close one of the connection without closing the other?

If you use UDP instead (specify SOCK_DGRAM instead of SOCK_STREAM), then you can specify a different address for each packet. Of course, note the multiple caveats with using UDP (no guaranteed delivery, no flow control whatsoever, and you have to do your own "connection management" because there's no such thing as a UDP connection).

> In this case I collect an error with CFSocketSendData and an alert view will be showed. What is the error?

Well, what did the UIAlertView say?

Comment: First of all, thank you for your reply. Yes, TCP is a connection oriented protocol with three way handshake phase. The apple documentation reports (for the second parameter of CFSocketSendData): "The address, stored as a struct sockaddr in a CFData object, to which to send the contents of data. If NULL, the data are sent to the address to which is is already connected". I think that the CFSocketSendData is responsable for making a connection also for TCP protocol. If I called CFSocketSendData with a different address after a connection has been established, it return an error.

Comment: The AlertView displays: Socket error as you can see from my code. However, the error code returned was -1 wich means (from apple documentaion): "The socket operation failed". At last, the connection can be closed by using the CFSocketInvalidate.

Comment: My bad; CFSocket doesn't seem to have any error reporting. UDP does not have "connections" per-se ("connecting" a UDP socket merely sets its default address). The documentation does not say that it establishes a connection; it merely says that if a connection is established, the data will go to that address. TCP does not support sending data to endpoints that you're not already connected to. Additionally, the code for CFSocketSendData clearly calls either send() or sendto() depending on whether you've specified an address: http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-550.42/CFSocket.c

Comment: Ok! Many thanks for your link and reply. Last days I studied the source code and I found a lots of answers to my doubts.